# How to define localization with defineMessages method?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I want to localize my component. I use yahoo/react-intl lib. I define some messages

```
const messages = defineMessages({
    greeting: {
        id: 'app.home.greeting',
        description: 'Message to greet the user.',
        defaultMessage: 'Hello!'
    },
  });
```

I don't know how to define a localizable text for message so I got this error

```
app.js:27785[React Intl] Missing message: "app.home.greeting" for locale: "nl", using default message as fallback.
```

Example of using

```
<input type="text" {...firstName} placeholder={intl.formatMessage(messages.greeting)} />
```

Does anyone know how to define localized messages?
It looks not possible to do this with defineMessages.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`defineMessages` is designed to work with the [babel-plugin of react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl).

In fact, it just helps you when extracting message defined somewhere in your code. This is useful in large code bases to keep the message-ids and translations in sync.

However, whether you use `defineMessages` or not you still need to provide the translations like this:

```
const translations = {
    'en-US': {
        'app.home.greeting': 'Hello!',
        'app.home.color.description': 'Please choose a color',
    },
    'en-GB': {
        'app.home.greeting': 'Hello!',
        'app.home.color.description': 'Please choose a colour',
    },
    de: {
        'app.home.greeting': 'Hallo!',
        'app.home.color.description': 'Bitte eine Farbe auswählen',
    }
 }

<IntlProvider locale="en" messages={translations.en}>
    <FormattedMessage
        id='app.home.color.description'
        description='A task description to choose a color'
        defaultMessage='Please choose a color'
    /> 
    <input type="text" {...firstName} placeholder={intl.formatMessage(messages.greeting)} />
</IntlProvider>
```

Of course you don’t need to wrap everything in a `IntlProvider`. Simply add one `IntlProvider` around your top-level/app component.

Comment: Yep, but actually I should define two messages with different ids for uk en translates. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you use one id for every string. I have edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: where is that `en` in `translations.en` coming from? and how would you pass that `translations` object globally so you can reuse it on various components?

Comment: @Sag1v I guess it should be `translations['en-US']`